# Populating a listbox with a text file first index of every line in the file

Tags: listbox, text-files, line, display, items

```
private void customersToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        custList.Text = "";
        FormControl();
        CustlistGB.Visible = true;
        CustlistGB.BringToFront();
        Optionchc.Visible = false;
        mainFormHandler.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(281, 367);
        custList.Text = "";

        fileloc = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"data\" + Todaysdate + @"\Customers.txt";
        if (!Directory.Exists(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"data\" + Todaysdate))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"data\" + Todaysdate);
        }
        using (var stream = new StreamWriter(@"data\" + Todaysdate + @"\Customers.txt", append: true))
        {
            stream.Close();
            int counter = 0;
            StreamReader read = new StreamReader(fileloc.ToString());
            List<string> users = new List<string>(File.ReadAllLines(fileloc));
            while (!read.EndOfStream)
            {
                string line = read.ReadLine();
                string[] tokens = line.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                foreach (string sx in tokens)
                {
                    custList.Text = tokens[0];
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have a problem getting my code to work. I'm trying to get the first "token"
in each line to appear in my listbox, but it is not appearing. When I click on 
the listbox while the app is running, it does however display the info of the first line in the labels when I click the listbox. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

this works:

```
listsup.Items.Clear();
        Supfile = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "data\\Suppliers.txt";
        List<string> proName = new List<string>();
        using (StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(Supfile))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = rdr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] val = line.Split(',');
                listsup.Items.Add(val[0]);
            }
        }
```